# How to track a scroll event in a graph?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using a chart with a custom date selector, while plotting a period of two years. I want to understand by a scroll event that I have reset one year and another year has started, while sending the event to the selector to change its header to the current one.
I can't get the event
[link][1]

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/nqt8v9e3/18/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `scroll` event listener to the `chart.scrollingContainer` HTML element and compare the proper values. For example:

```
let nexYearStartPx;
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      render: function() {
        nexYearStartPx = this.xAxis[0].toPixels(11.5); // start of Jan/12 category
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  ...
});

chart.scrollingContainer.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  if (chart.scrollingContainer.scrollLeft + chart.chartWidth > nexYearStartPx) {
    console.log('Next year visible!');
  }
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bx4neayL/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels